# how to solve nonlinear differential equations which calls other functions that uses states and time as input while solving NDSolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have nonlinear differential equations which require output from other functions and those functions require time and some states as input.

I'm writing the Mathematica code bellow the equation.

$p=\sqrt{1-\left(1-\frac{h}{25}\right)^2}$

```
p[h_] := Sqrt[1 - (1 - 2*(h/50))^2];
```

$q=p \left(\text{x1}^2 \sin (t)+\text{x2}^2 \cos (t)+\sin (2 t)\right)$

```
q[t_, x2_, x1_, h_] := (x2^2*Cos[t] + x1^2*Sin[t] +Sin[2*t])*p[h];
```

$r=p \left(\text{x1}^2 \cos (t)+\text{x2}^2 \sin (t)+\cos (2 t)\right)$

```
r[t_, x2_, x1_, h_] := (x1^2*Cos[t] + x2^2*Sin[t] +Cos[2*t])*p[h];
```

$alp=\tan ^{-1}(q,r)$ if q non zero and r non zero

```
alp[t_, x2_, x1_, h_] :=If[q[t, h, x1, x2] == 0 && r[t, h, x1, x2] == 0, 0, ArcTan[q[t, h, x1, x2],r[t, h, x1, x2]]];
```

$f1=alp*p*q* \sqrt{q^2+r^2} $

$f2=alp*p*r* \sqrt{q^2+r^2} $

$g1=\int_0^{\text{hmax}} \text{f1} \,dh$

$g2=\int_0^{\text{hmax}} \text{f2} \,dh$

```
g[t1_, x11_, x21_]:=Module[{t = t1, x1 = x11, x2 = x21}, 
    h = Range[0, 10, 0.1]; cc = ConstantArray[0, Length[h] - 1]; 
     f1 = cc; f2 = cc; For[i = 1, i < Length[h], i++, 
      h1 = (h[[i]] + h[[i + 1]])*0.5; 
       p1 = Sqrt[1 - (1 - 2*(h1/50))^2]; f[t, x1, x2, h1] := 
        p1*Sin[alp[t, x1, x2, h1]]*Sqrt[q[t, x1, x2, h1]^2 + 
           r[t, x1, x2, h1]^2]*{q[t, x1, x2, h1], r[t, x1, x2, h1], 
          0}*(-h[[i]] + h[[i + 1]]); f1[[i]] = f[t, x1, x2, h1][[
         1]]; f2[[i]] = f[t, x1, x2, h1][[2]]; ]; 
     g1 = Total[f1, {1}]; g2 = Total[f2, {1}]; {g1, g2}];
```

linear equations in y1, y2 and y3

Equation 1

$\frac{\text{y1} (10 \sin (\text{x1})+\cos (\text{x2}))}{1000000}+\frac{1}{10} \text{y2} (0.1 \sin (\text{x1})+6 \cos (\text{x2}))+\frac{1}{100} \text{y3} (\sin (\text{x1})+4 \cos (\text{x2}))=\int_0^{\text{hmax}} \text{f1} \, dh+\text{x1}^2 \sin (t)+\cos (t)+2.5 $

Equation 2

$\frac{\text{y1} (5 \cos (\text{x1})+\sin (\text{x2}))}{1000}+\frac{1}{100} \text{y3} (\cos (\text{x1})+4 \sin (\text{x2}))+\frac{\text{y2} (2 \sin (\text{x2})+40 \cos (\text{x2}))}{1000000}= \text{x2}^2 \left(\int_0^{\text{hmax}} \text{f2} \, dh\right)+\sin (t)+2$

Equation 3

$\frac{1}{10} \text{y3} (20 \cos (\text{x1}(t))+\sin (\text{x2}(t)))+\frac{\text{y1} (4 \sin (\text{x1})+0.5 \sin (\text{x2}))}{1000000}+\frac{\text{y2} (4 \sin (\text{x1})+0.1 \cos (\text{x2}))}{1000}=\text{x1} \sin (t)+\cos (t)+\text{x2}+1.5 $

```
l1[t_, x2_, x1_] := (y1*(10*Sin[x1] + Cos[x2]))/10^6 + 
    (y2*(Sin[x1]*0.1 + 6*Cos[x2]))/10 + (y3*(Sin[x1] + 4*Cos[x2]))/
     10^2; 
l4[t_, x2_, x1_] := g[t, x1, x2][[1]] + x1^2*Sin[t] + Cos[t] + 2.5; 
l2[t_, x2_, x1_] := (y1*(Sin[x2] + 5*Cos[x1]))/10^3 + 
    (y2*(40*Cos[x2] + 2*Sin[x2]))/10^6 + (y3*(4*Sin[x2] + Cos[x1]))/
     10^2; 
l5[t_, x2_, x1_] := x2^2*g[t, x1, x2][[2]] + Sin[t] + 2; 
l3[t_, x2_, x1_] := (y1*(0.5*Sin[x2] + 4*Sin[x1]))/10^6 + 
    (y2*(0.1*Cos[x2] + 4*Sin[x1]))/10^3 + 
    (y3*(Sin[x2] + 20*Cos[x1]))/10; 
l6[t_, x2_, x1_] := Sin[t]*x1 + x2 + Cos[t] + 1.5;
```

Combining equations now

```
eq[t_, x2_, x1_] := {l1[t, x1, x2] == l4[t, x1, x2], 
    l2[t, x1, x2] == l5[t, x1, x2], l3[t, x1, x2] == 
     l6[t, x1, x2]}; 
y11[t_, x1_, x2_] := NSolve[eq[t, x1, x2], {y1, y2, y3}][[1]] /. 
    {Rule -> Set}; 
ynew1[t_, x1_, x2_] := y11[t, x1, x2][[1]]; 
ynew3[t_, x1_, x2_] := y11[t, x1, x2][[3]];
```

Here I'm facing the problem.

$\text{x1}'=\text{x1}*\text{y1}+\text{x2}*\text{y3}$

$\text{x2}'=\text{x2}*\text{y3}-\text{x2}*\text{y1}$

$\text{x3}'=\text{x1}*\text{x2}*\cos (t)+\sin (t)+\text{x4}$

$\text{x4}'=\text{x3}^2* \sin (t)+\text{x4}$

$ x1(0)=0.01, x2(0)=0.1, x3(0)=0, x4(0)=0 $

$x'$ implies derivative with time 't'.

How to update ynew1 and ynew3 every time with new x1 and x2 as x1 and x2 are a function of time?. My question might boil down to how to write this differential equation in NDSolveValue. Kindly anyone help me.

```
diffeq = {Derivative[1][x1][t] == x1*ynew1[t, x1, x2] - 
      Cross[{ynew1[t, x1, x2], 0, ynew3[t, x1, x2]}, {x1, x2, 0}][[
       1]], Derivative[1][x2][t] == x2*ynew3[t, x1, x2] - 
      Cross[{ynew1[t, x1, x2], 0, ynew3[t, x1, x2]}, {x1, x2, 0}][[
       2]], Derivative[1][x3][t] == Sin[t] + x1*x2*Cos[t], 
    Derivative[1][x4][t] == x3^2*Sin[t], x1[0] == 0.01, 
    x2[0] == 0.01, x3[0] == 0, x4[0] == 0}; 
xsol = NDSolve[diffeq, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}]; 
Plot[xsol[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All
```

Comment: Please make some effort to simplify the sample.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what does this mean "simplify the sample". I will do it just need to know what it is

Comment: You may want to read the following:  0. https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871 1. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example 2. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks. I will do it